# can somebody explain this statement form flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

"In unbounded constraints, they try to fit their children in that direction. In this case, you cannot set flex on the children to anything other than 0 (the default). In the widget library, this means that you cannot use Expanded when the flex box is inside another flex box or inside a scrollable. If you do, you’ll get an exception message pointing you at this document."

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints#flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default (main axis) size of the column or row is the minimum size to contain its children. Normally these children have a fix height. For example, if the column has 3 children with 50 height, the column's height is going to be 150. But flexible widgets are an exception.

Flexible widgets calculate their sizes by dividing the available space by their flex factor. If the column containing the flexible widget is not constrained, this available space is infinity. So infinity/flexFactor is still infinity. (In practice you get an exception instead of an infinitely sized widget)

The solution for this problem is to put the column or row widget into a fix sized widget.

**For example:** you want to make a column with the height of 500 with 2 children with 50 height, and one, that fills the available space. You can wrap your column widget in a 500 tall sized box, and wrap child number 3 in an expanded widget. The expanded widget fills all the remaining space. In code:

```
SizedBox(
    height: 500,
    child: Column(
      children:
      [
        Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red,),
        Container(height: 50, color: Colors.blue,),
        Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

[the result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWVNj.png)

[Flexible](https://youtu.be/CI7x0mAZiY0) and [expanded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo) widgets are explained in these videos.